# Why are my LDAP logins slow?

Tags: server, ssh, login, sudo, ldap

I have been running this server with LDAP for about 6 months. The logins have always been fast. However, starting this week logins are taking 1-2 minutes to complete. This include ssh, sudo su, and local logins. The Openldap database is being hosted by the server that is having the speed problems. I have two other servers that use this same openldap database for authentication, they don't have any problems with speed. The server is ubuntu server 12.04 lts running OpenLDAP 2.4.28. The two working servers are both running ubuntu server 12.04 lts also. I did notice that when logging in I get a Failed to add entry for user mbrown. Just after the login completes.
 I have tried adding

```
UseDNS no
```

to `/etc/sshd_config` and have also tried commenting out the line

```
session        optional pam_ck_connector.so nox11
```

from `/etc/pam.d/common-session`.

Neither has sped up the login. I have also verified that my `/etc/hosts` file is correctly set up.

What else could be causing such a slow login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up digging through a backup and restoring all the files from `/etc/pam.d`. this appears to have fixed the slow login problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally what worked for me was a change in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` on the machine you see slow logins for (ie. the server). 
The change:

```
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

To

```
#session optional pam_systemd.so
```

I saw that solution in the [following question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150933/why-is-ssh-too-slow-when-i-access-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider disabling **LDAP_Referals** on your system's `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` configuration file.

```
ldap_referrals = false
```

This is a known performance issue and is described on the sssd man-page: https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-ldap

> ###### ldap_referrals (boolean)
>
> Specifies whether automatic referral chasing should be enabled.
>
> - Please note that sssd only supports referral chasing when it is compiled with OpenLDAP version 2.4.13 or higher.
> - Chasing referrals may incur a performance penalty in environments that use them heavily, a notable example is Microsoft Active Directory. If your setup does not in fact require the use of referrals, **setting this option to false might bring a noticeable performance improvement.**