# Why is ssh too slow when I access in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and set the network and I configured NIS client to get user information from the server.

The problem is when I access this server through ssh, it is too slow to get a shell from the server. I've been digging out to solve this problem and found this error message from `/var/log/auth.log` but I don't know how to do that. What should I do?

```
Jun 13 08:55:08 server sshd[1716]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is induced by the network interface, netplan, which is newly adapted in Ubuntu 18.04. Usually, when users configure this interface, they put `optional: true` attribute in the `*.yaml` to set an ethernet like below.

```
network:
    version: 2

    ethernets:
       ens5:
       addresses: []
       dhcp4: true
       optional: true
```

The reason why they put that attr is because if there is no attr in the file, it will hang in a certain amount of time on boot showing the message.

```
a start job is running for wait for network to be configured
```

But the problem is that when you put this attr, an optional instruction in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` runs and this makes an error while you are trying to make a connection to the server

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-session
...
session optional pam_systemd.so
...
```

So, you need to comment out to get rid of time out while making a connection or session with the server.

```
# session optional pam_systemd.so
```